# std::forward with copy-on-write branching

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I'm attempting to do something to the effect of

```
template <typename T>
void somemethod (T&& t) {
    foo(static_cast<const T&>(t));
    bar(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

such that

1. if `foo()` makes changes to `t`, it operates on a copy instead. (something like copy-on-write)
2. once `foo()` is done with `t`, `t` is forwarded straight to `bar()`

Is this possible? Is it correct as written? Will the compiler understand what I am trying to do?

Do I need to make some helper class to implement this instead?

Similarly, what if I was attempting something to the effect of:

```
template <typename T>
void somemethod (T&& t) {
    foo(std::forward<T>(t));
    bar(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

such that

1. the same `t` used by `foo()` is then forwarded to `bar()`

Comment: _"I'm pretty sure this means copy-on-write"_ Well, not really with free functions, you'll loose the _copy_ in that case, unless you provide some returned value that allows to access this copy.

Answer (score 0):

Copy-on-write is a property of a class, there is no good way you can cause that to happen in `somemethod`.  You *can* prevent `foo` from accidentally modifying the parameter, by giving it a `const` parameter, which you're doing, but you're also passing it as an rvalue, which is unnecessary, and wierd. I've never seen a use-case for `const T&&`.  People either use `const T&` or `T&` or `T&&`.  In your case, I would recommend `const T&`.

```
template<class T> //I'm assuming you forgot to paste this bit
void somemethod (T&& t) {
    foo(static_cast<const T&>(t));
    bar(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

If you *really* wanted to be absolutely certain that `foo` could not sabatoge `t` under any circumstances, you could give it a copy of `t` instead of the const reference, but that's overkill for any sane situation.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better solutions to this problem, but you could do

```
template <typename T>
void somemethod (T&& t) {
    T tmp_t = foo(std::forward<T>(t));
    bar(std::forward<T>(tmp_t));
}
```

or even simpler:

```
template <typename T>
void somemethod (T&& t) {
    bar(foo(std::forward<T>(t)));
}
```

This way foo has a way to report if it actually changed anything, but it's signature must be changed:

```
template <typename T>
T foo(T&& t){
    if (want_to_modify){
        T result;
        // here you insert data that get modified form t
        return std::forward<T>(result);
    }else{
        return std::forward<T>(t);
    }
}
```

}

This way an instance of `T` is just passed through `foo` if not modified.

Other way of doing it, would be to implement copy-on-write directly into `T`, but if you don't need it everywhere where you use `T`, this is probably a better solution.